# Building react.js fails with "This socket is closed"

Tags: gruntjs, reactjs

I cloned the react repo https://github.com/facebook/react and did a build as described in the readme. executing grunt fails immediately however:

```
H:\github\react>grunt
Running "delete-build-modules" task

Running "jsx:normal" (jsx) task
Warning: This socket is closed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Not an expert with grunt or node. Any hint how I can get the build done? Did other people succeed building react on windows?

Comment: I've stumbled upon the same issue. Any advice (if possible to get it to run on windows) would be awesome.

Comment: looks like the problem lies in calling the scripts in thebin folder. since windows does not support the shebang. renaming the 2 scripts to *.cmd might help, but I did not get it working. I added an issue at github but looks like it does not get attention soon. downloading the starterkit gives you the files resulting from the build.